# get a type from string array?

Tags: typescript, types

I have trouble getting a type from an array, which allows one of the elements of the array.

this is the Array.

```
export const translationSettings = [
  'districtName',
  'district',
  'id',
  "area",
  "changeDate",
  "parcelId",
  'typeBotanical',
  'typeGerman',
  'height',
  'borough',
  'owner',
  'genus',
  'genusGerman',
  'diameterCrown',
  'plantingYear',
  'diameterTrunk',
  'age',
  'street',
]
```

this is the type I came up with:

```
export type TranslationSettings = Partial<typeof nationStates[number]>;
```

I now want to use it like this:

```
const translation : Record<string, TranslationSettings > = {
  namgmk: 'districtName',
  gmk: 'district',
  uuid: 'id',
  afl: "area",
  statusdat: "changeDate",
  fsko: "parcelId"
}
```

the strange (for me) error is:

> Type '"districtName"' is not assignable to type 'TranslationSettings'.ts(2322)

what I want is, that in the translation object the Key can be a random string, the Value must be one of the array from translationSettings.

any help would be great!
thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `nationStates`?

Comment: (Presumably `nationStates` is a typo; please fix it.)  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKpbzw) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?